# Select latest entry from MySQL database error

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("jmvarela_jacket") or die(mysql_error());

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `quote` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1'; 

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
echo $row['frase'];
?>
```

I cant get this to work.

I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in
>   /home/jmvarela/public_html/ihateyourjacket.com/latest/index.php
>   on line 7

I am trying to select the latest entry to the mysql database.

The table is called "quote"

There are three fields: id, frase and name.

Just to clarify (because this could be VERY bad coding) I am trying to get the "biggest" id and to display it's correspondant "frase".

Comment: Can you please give the exact error or problem you're having?

Comment: @InSane, i edited my question but could understand the second question! sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have not perform your query

> $result = mysql_query($query);
>
> $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

try this

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are not **running** the query.

```
// construct the query.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `quote` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1'; 

// run the query..THIS IS MISSING.
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Also it's better to change `SELECT *` to `SELECT frase`,    since you're interested only in the `frase` column. This will not bring all the    unwanted columns from MySql to PHP, making your    program perform better.

Comment: sorry cant see how the code should end up! Should i still use     $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query );
echo $row['frase'];

Comment: @Trufa: Yes. End it as you were ending it before.

Comment: thanks I got it to work with Bhanu´s answer but thanks for the tips! very clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sure if this should be done but ill leave the complete running code for future refence.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("jmvarela_jacket") or die(mysql_error());

// construct the query.
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `quote` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1'; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
echo $row['frase'];
?>
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Clear question with code sample?  Check.  Response to comment asking for clarification?  Check.  Upvoted/Accepted answer(s) that were helpful?  Check.  Complete code listing of final solution?  Check.  I wish everyone would cover all the bases so thoroughly!  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard. Thank you very much. It´s been a great ride so far and I´m sure it´s just starting. Cheers!